# Find all points within N meters of a geographic border using geopandas

Tags: geopandas

I need to find all points (name, latitude, longitude) within N meters of the U.S. border. My approach is:

1. Make a geodataframe that contains a multipolygon where each polygon is a buffered border.

```
# Get the U.S. borders
border = gpd.read_file('cb_2018_us_nation_5m')
border = border.to_crs("EPSG:32636")
# Get just the boundary
just_border = border.boundary
# Put a 10km buffer around the line. We now have multiple polygons (AK, HI, CONUS), each that look like a donut.
border_buffered = just_border.buffer(10000, cap_style=3, join_style=2)
```

Then turn my dataframe into a geodataframe.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(temp, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(temp.Longitude, temp.Latitude))
gdf = gdf.set_crs("EPSG:32636")
```

Then clip the points within the polygons.

```
ngdf = gpd.clip(gdf, border_buffered, keep_geom_type=False)
```

That finds no points:

```
ngdf.shape
(0, 15)
```

So I try using a mask:

```
gdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
gdf.shape
(25746326, 17)
pip_mask = gdf.within(border_buffered.loc[0, 'geometry'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kovar/work/a50_utils/foo.py", line 45, in <module>
    pip_mask = gdf.within(border_buffered.loc[0, 'geometry'])
  File "/Users/kovar/miniforge3/envs/a50-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 889, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/Users/kovar/miniforge3/envs/a50-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1063, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "/Users/kovar/miniforge3/envs/a50-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 720, in _has_valid_tuple
    self._validate_key_length(key)
  File "/Users/kovar/miniforge3/envs/a50-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 761, in _validate_key_length
    raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

I'm guessing that I have too many polygons, or the buffered lines are too complex.

Comment: 1. do you have sample data for points you wish to test?  2. within N meters of border, is this both within (i.e. Texas) and outside (i.e. Mexico) but exclude well within (i.e. Kansas)

Comment: Please post the [entire traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors - they're really helpful for debugging ;) It looks like `border_buffered` is a GeoSeries, not a GeoDataFrame, as `GeoDataFrame.boundary` just returns a `GeoSeries`, so just do `border_buffered.loc[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your question clearly states N meters.  This needs to use UTM CRS geometry.  The US boundary passes through multiple UTM CRS zones
- start by associating a part of border with a UTM zone (line segments)
- with each line segment use appropriate UTM CRS and add buffer. This example creates a 50KM buffer.  There are some issues,  hence if necessary size of buffer is reduced
- now have geo data frame with polygons that include buffer, plus columns to show actual line string and actual buffer used

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import requests, io
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# fmt: off
# US geometry
url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_nation_5m.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

gdf2 = gpd.read_file(list(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.shp"))[0])
gdf2["geometry"] = gdf2["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.boundary)

# get UTM zones
utm = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/b294795270aa4fb3bd25286bf09edc51_0.geojson").json()).set_crs(gdf2.crs)
utm = utm.loc[~utm["ZONE"].eq(0)]
# fmt: on

# join US boundary to UTM zomes using spatial join, i.e. segments of boundary that pass through multiple zone
us_utm = gpd.sjoin(utm, gdf2)
us_utm = us_utm.merge(
    gdf2["geometry"], left_on="index_right", right_index=True, suffixes=("", "_right")
)

# create linestrings for each zone / boundary segment
us_utm_sects = us_utm["geometry"].intersection(gpd.GeoSeries(us_utm["geometry_right"]))

# function to create a buffer on line seqment
def buffer(g, buffer=1):
    gdf_sect = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[g], crs="EPSG:4326")
    utm_crs = gdf_sect.estimate_utm_crs()
    while True:
        g2 = gdf_sect.to_crs(utm_crs).buffer(buffer, cap_style=2).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
        tb = g2.total_bounds[[0,2]]
        bounds = abs(tb[0] - tb[1])
        # make sure epsg:4326 geometry makes sense, if not reduce size of buffer on this segment
        if bounds < 60:
            break
        buffer = buffer / 2
    return {"geometry": g2.values[0], "utm_crs": str(utm_crs), "line_geometry":g, "buffer":buffer}


# create geo data frame of us border with 50km buffer
us_buf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(us_utm_sects.apply(buffer, buffer=5 * 10 ** 4).apply(pd.Series))
us_buf["color"] = pd.factorize(us_buf["utm_crs"])[0]
```

#### use it

- have used world wide earthquakes to demonstrate
- simple case of doing spatial join between points and buffered US border
- have hovered over an earthquake in Mexico near US border to demonstrate it has worked

```
gdf_eq = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
    requests.get(
        "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.geojson"
    ).json()
)

# earthquakes near US border...
us_eq = gpd.sjoin(gdf_eq, us_buf)

px.scatter_mapbox(us_eq, lat=us_eq.geometry.y, lon=us_eq.geometry.x, hover_data=["title"]).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom":1,
        "center":{"lat":sum(us_eq.total_bounds[[0,2]])/2,"lon":sum(us_eq.total_bounds[[1,3]])/2},
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": us_buf.geometry.__geo_interface__,
                "type": "fill",
                "color": "yellow",
                "opacity": 0.2,
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l":0,"t":0,"b":0,"r":0}
    
)
```

#### filter just Mexico border

- simply spacial join to Mexico polygon

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).set_crs("EPSG:4326")
us_buf = gpd.sjoin(us_buf, world.loc[world["iso_a3"].eq("MEX")]).drop(columns=["index_right"])
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thorough, and very complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: With Python 3.9 and shapely 1.8.0 the following warnings are given:

```.../pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py:1638: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  result[:] = values
.../pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py:112: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead.
  values = construct_1d_object_array_from_listlike(values)```

Comment: I'm aware of the warnings, I believe they are unavoidable as they are embedded in pandas / geopandas code, not the user code.

Comment: Thank you. I was just about to look for the source of them! Will look for geopandas to catch up.

Comment: here's a minimal piece of code that generates the warnings `us_utm_sects.apply(lambda g: [g])` ... I don't see anyway to eliminate

Comment: I tried doing this with just the Mexican border using https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/mexico-and-us-border/explore. I referenced the file directly as I could not find a URL for it.

Using this shapefile, I get `KeyError: 'utm_crs'`, presumably because us_utm is empty after the .sjoin.

Is there a way to handle the single border case as well as the multi-zone case?

Thank you.

Comment: If I know what rows in us_buf represent the border I want to work with, I could filter the others out after building us_buf with the entire border.

Comment: updated answer - simply sjoin to Mexico geometry

Comment: Thank you -very- much. Both use cases now work. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting Michael's comment to an answer.

"It looks like border_buffered is a GeoSeries, not a GeoDataFrame, as GeoDataFrame.boundary just returns a GeoSeries, so just do border_buffered.loc[0]"

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888719/michael-delgado

This solved the problem.